# Symfony choice field linked with Entity does not display the saved value as selected when editing

Tags: php, symfony

I have a dropdown field on a form that i have managed to link with an Entity, all options that are being displayed are pulled from database.

```
->add('project', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AdminBundle:Programs',
                'property' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'Assigned Program'
```

When I save the form I can get the value from the dropdown to save in database. My problem is when i reopen the form to edit the user information the above dropdown field does not show the saved value as selected by default, where as the rest of the fields on a form are pre-filled with saved data.

Now I know i can use the `'data' => xyz` to set the default value but how do i do it in a case when the dropdown is linked with an Entity

Comment: For that you'd need to use the `query_builder` of your form, search for the project linked to your user, and you'll have your form working the way I think you want. But the way I understand your problem, you need your form to have a different behavior if the user has a project linked or not. And for that you'll need listeners. I hope this helps and I get what you're trying to do correctly

Comment: If everything else is set up correctly, what you have should work. So I guess there might be a problem in how you're persisting your entites, or how their relations are configured. Please show that code too.